# Execute Build Jobs/Pipelines not on Master but only on Build Agent

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

Following the [Jenkins Best Practices](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Best+Practices), I want to avoid that Build Jobs/Pipelines could be executed into my Jenkins Master. 
To do so, I've installed the [Job Restrictions Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/job-restrictions), using it to configure the Master to run only some Maintenance Pipelines. 
The problem is that now Build Pipelines that are configured to run on specific Agents, are not executed anymore. I see that the Build Queue continuously grows, and the Pipelines are not runned. I think that this behaviour could be related to Flyweight Executors of the Master. 
So, the question is the following: **How can I execute on Master just a little subset of Maintenance Pipelines and, in the mean time, execute Build Pipelines only on specific Agent?**

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. However, an actual answer/solution should **not** be edited into your question. In general, you should [edit] the question to *clarify* it, but not to include an answer within it. You should create your own answer with the code/solution you used to solve your problem, and then accept it (the system may require a 48 hour delay prior to doing so). When you've solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution that perfectly fits with my needs, [here](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31866?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&showAll=true). 
To quickly sum up the solution, I was to able to exclude all the user Builds from Master and run on it only the Jobs/Pipelines of a specific Jenkins folder (IuA in my case), configuring the Job Restrictions Plugin in the following way:

[image: Job Restrictions Configuration]

In order to better understand the logic behind this solution, I recommend you to give a look at link that I posted above.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the master node to only be used when explicitly named. Just click the master node > go to configure and change `Use this node as much as possible` to `Only build jobs with label expressions matching this node`

Comment: I already have this configuration: in this way everyone that knows the Master label can run his Build Jobs/Pipelines inside the Master.

Comment: Yes, that is usually the thing with best practices. You can just set the build executors of the master to zero. But this only becomes relevant if you have a huge amount of persons working on pipelines